# How to set actions on close button in AWT Dialog?

Tags: java, netbeans, awt

I created the dialog with NetBeans wizard like this:

```
Dialog wizardDialog = DialogDisplayer.getDefault().createDialog(new CustomWizardDescriptor);
```

I want to create an asking window when the user clicks the Close button (or Cancel button near Prev and Next buttons), which specifies whether the user wants to close the window with unsaved data. So, if the user does not want to close the window, the dialog remains open.

I can add the WindowListener for dialog and override windowClosing(), but how to stop the process of closing the dialog in this method? AWT component Dialog doesnt have method setCloseOperation(NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) like a JDialog...

Comment: AWT? Seriously? don't use it, use the JDialog. Swing is already somewhat 'out of date' and replaced by JavaFX, but in some cases, I assume it makes sense to use it. but AWT??

Comment: I know :D But this is an old and big project, the first developers used it according to the Definitive Guide to NetBeans Platform 7 by Apress. We are using Swing in this project, but not HERE:( I cant refactor the all project to Swing))